# Jasperstudio table export for ODS, ODT, XLSX missing line at the bottom

Tags: jasper-reports

When export table report to the following media there are problem as follows

1. XLSX - missing bottom line
2. ODS - missing data (empty)
3. ODT - missing left line

kindly advise

[image]

This is the jrxml file for the report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->
<!-- 2016-10-27T15:55:54 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Picked-Up Laid-Down Drill Pipe" pageWidth="850" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="810" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1e75f5a5-e587-4438-a7bb-811f63f62f2e">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.3" value="columnHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.3" value="*"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.4" value="columnFooter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.frames.as.nested.tables" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.page.height" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.create.custom.palette" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.force.page.breaks" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.background" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.max.rows.per.sheet" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.size.fix.enabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://172.18.110.151:8081/jasperserver_pro/"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="anovasupport"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value=""/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value=""/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="f09aa0aa-f0df-4726-ae0e-7b49bcb54c0f">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value=""/>
        <parameter name="pup_operation_parameter" class="java.util.Collection"/>
        <parameter name="pup_assembly_parameter" class="java.util.Collection"/>
        <queryString>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. What version of *JR* are you using?

Comment: @AlexK verions 6.3

Comment: It is better to post the simple *jrxml* to reproduce a problem

Comment: ok i updated the jrxml file and by the way i solved the XLXS missing bottom line...now left the ODT missing left line and also the ODS empty table